# Show that $\Gamma \vDash_{taut} B \leftrightarrow \Gamma \cup \{\lnot B\}$ is unsatisfiable.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm going through an example proof, and I'm unclear why it's important to write: Let $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot B\}=A_1,...A_n,\lnot B$, why not let $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot B\}=\lnot B$.

By definition of $\Gamma=\lnot B \vDash_{taut} B, v(\lnot B), v(B)=\textbf{t}$ however this is in conflict of the definition of $F_{\lnot}(v(B))=\textbf{t}$ as $v(B)$ must $=\textbf{f}$.

Therefore either $v(\lnot B), v(B)$ will be $\textbf{f}$, and the statement is unsatisfiable?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is a set of formuals; it can be infinite.

Comment: Apply the def of $\Gamma \vDash_{\text {taut}} B$ and consider if it is possible to have some $v$ that satisfies all formulas in $\Gamma$ and $v(\lnot B)= \text t$.

Comment: That choice is the same as choosing $\Gamma=\varnothing$. You can do that, but that's not what you're trying to prove. It's a special case. If $B$ is a propositional variable then $\not\vDash_{taut} B$, however we have $\{B\}\vDash_{taut} B$ which the theorem then suggests that $\{B,\neg B\}$ is unsatisfiable but isn't covered by your special case.